# Libgdx : Best way to know when something was touched

Tags: java, android, libgdx

So let's say I have an image of 128x128.

What is the easiest way to know that this image was touched/clicked on?

Is the possible way only through getting the x and y coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

What exact class do you mean:

- com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actors.Image
- com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image

?

Maybe you mean using the image in Sprite class?

Please provide more information. There are different approaches.

For example class *com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actors.Image* has implementation of the logic of its geometry and you should only override its *touchUp* method and add your logic here.

Answer (score -1):

If the image is part of the ViewGroup i mean a view then you can always implement the OnClickListener and override the onClick(View v) method:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.image_btn:
            // your code goes here.
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

    }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

You can Use to varify:

```
 imgResult.setOnTouchListener(new OnClickListener() {           
                public void onClick(View v) {    
        System.out.println("Somethog is touched");    
      }    
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

You should extends Canvas class.

Override OnDraw() Method and create point's zone for your image.

Point[][] points = new Point[5][5] 
Then lay it(use relation layout) to your screen.

Get zone where you touch it.
if(points[i][j] == your Touch(get coordinates)){

}